# Is a Class the same thing as an Object

Tags: java, class, object, instantiation

If I have a

```
class A{ }

class B extends A{ }
```

and I instantiate a reference variable "var"

```
A var = new B();
```

Is "var" then considered to be instantiated as a "B" Object? Where A is the variable reference type and not the Object instantiated for "var".

Comment: class = cookie cutter. object = cookie.

Comment: `var` is a variable with reference type `A` pointing to a new instance of class `B`.

Answer (score 0):

The object type is still B no matter how you refer to it. That is, the code `var.getClass()` would return B instead of A, therefore the class of "var" is B.

You could also say that "var" is an instance of A and the code `boolean isA = (var instanceof A)` would return true, but `var.getClass()` would not return A.

Comment: Make up your mind about the return value of `var.getClass()`.  Now you have it both ways.

Comment: _the class of "var" is B_ Be very careful. `var` is a variable. Its declared type is `A`. Its dynamic type is the type of the instance it's referencing, which is `B`.

Comment: What would be the benefit in having the class of "var" be B if you are accessing Class A methods. Why not just instantiate it as: A var = new A(); instead of A var = new B(); ? I guess I'm trying to figure out for what reason you would upcast.

Answer (score 0):

`A` and `B` are both classes. A class is a blueprint, and an object is an instantiation of a class.

However, a variable neither *is* an object nor holds an object. A variable only holds the *location* of an object. Therefore, object variables (i.e. non-primitive variables) are called *reference variables* in Java.

In this specific case, we would say that the variable `var` is of type `A` but references an object of type `B`. Even though `var` references a `B` object, it can only access the methods defined in parent `A` because it is of type `A`.

Comment: So why do we need to call it a type A variable if it only matters what object type it references in order to call methods in that class?

Comment: In my mind it really only matters the class for which the object is being instantiated. I don't see how the definition of the variable for a type and the object should be different.

Comment: But the thing is, if a variable is of type `A`, it can only use the methods defined for an `A` object, even if the variable actually references some child object of `A` (e.g. a `B` object).

Comment: Ok, that I understand. But then what would be the benefit in having the class of variable "var" be B if you are accessing Class A methods. Why not just instantiate it as: A var = new A(); instead of A var = new B(); ? I guess I'm trying to figure out for what reason you would upcast.

Comment: Lets say the parent class is Bear with Black and Grizzly children classes. We want to use a Bear, but we're just going to have it walk, something that any type of Bear can do. So, we use a Bear variable with, let's say, a Grizzly object. This way, we are showing that we're only interested in common functionality of all Bears and that the actual type of Bear can be changed freely.

Comment: Ok, the term "common functionality" really is starting to help me make sense of the issue. What I'm thinking is that, for example, in the case of the Bear and (Black and Grizzly) subclasses, the method for walking could be placed in Bear. Where in fact Bear could be an interface with a "walk" method accessed by the subclasses that are more specific. Thus common functionality methods shared by all subclasses can be place in the parent class Bear. Thus the need to access it with a type reference variable.

Comment: You're definitely catching the drift! Although we don't *need* to upcast like this, it allows for another layer of generality. As programmers, the more general we can make our code, the easier code reuse and becomes.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a reference of type `A`. It points to an object of type `B`. However, it only knows about the methods that are exposed in `A`. So, if class `B` defines a method not present in `A`, you won't be able to call them from the `var` reference.

Comment: So if it points to object of type B, why does it only know about methods exposed in A? Wouldn't it make sense to be able to access methods in B if it is an object of type B?

Comment: The reference is of type A. It doesn't know that B exists. Think of it as polaroid sunglasses, you only see the horizontal lightbeams (or something else, if that wasn't a good allegory for you ;)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is going to be successfully casted to `A`, but you are not going to be able to access any `B` specific properties from `A` . See [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 0):

A var = new B();
This is a typical example of upcasting in Java.
RHS indicates that object of type B is instantiated in the memory by its default no-args constructor. But you need a reference variable to point to the memory. So in LHS "A var" , var is the reference variable of type A . Since in Java, runtime polymorphism or Dynamic method dispatch is allowed in which call to the overridden method is resolved at runtime rather than compile time and the overridden method is called through the reference variable of the superclass.

So in short. Object of B is instantiated and for achieving runtime polymorphism, it is reference variable of type A.

Hope this understanding will help in discovering your answer.